# How to fetch xml attribute value in liquid template - XML to JSON Liquid

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dotliquid, xml-to-json, liquid-template

I am trying to fetch the xml attribute value using liquid template. Examples are as below.

XML example:

```
    <ns0:root xmlns:ns0="http://customnamespace.com" xmlns:ns1="http://customnamespace2.com">
  <ns1:product>
  <ns1:name QualifierID="std.lang.all" >TV</ns1:name>
  <ns1:price>499.9</ns1:price>
 </ns1:product>
 </ns0:root>
```

Liquid Template used:

```
{
"name": "{{content.product.name['QualifierID']}}",
"price": "{{content.product.price}}",
}
```

Output expecting :

```
  {
"name": "std.lang.all",
"price": "499.9"
```

}

I tried couple of ways but not able to fetch the xml attribute value. it gives me empty value for name.

Best Regards,

Suraj

Answer (score 2):

According to some test, it seems we can't get the attribute(QualifierID) value of the xml by liquid. And I also can not find any useful information about getting attribute value of xml by liquid. But I can provide a workaround for your reference, please refer to my logic below.

**1.** I initialize a variable named `xmlString` and set the value with your xml data to simulate your situation.
[image]

**2.** I initialize another variable named `jsonString` and set its value with converting the `xmlString` to json.
[image]

**3.** After that, use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the `jsonString` we get above. And then use "[Compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action)" action to compose the json data which you expected.(The schema in "Parse JSON" was generated by the result from "Initialize variable 2").
[image]

Hope it helps~

Comment: Hi @Hury :  yep it works with the JSON parsing, but i was trying to see if we can directly fetch it from the xml and doesn't look like we can do that at the moment. Thanks

Comment: XML received is ISO 8859-1 encoded and after doing this, it is leaving extra characters in field for "°C" like this "Â°C"